# Creating a multi-frame gif with a gobal color table in .NET

Tags: .net, wpf, image-manipulation

I am trying to create a multi-frame gif with .NET to gain more compression than save each of the images in a single file.

My approach is to use the GifBitmapEncoder from the WPF PresentationCore like this:

```
GifBitmapEncoder e = new GifBitmapEncoder();  
e.Frames.Add(frame1);  
e.Frames.Add(frame2);  
...  
e.Save(myStream);
```

The result of this is a correct multi-frame gif but the size is nearly the same as saving single files. I guess the reason is that the GifBitmapEncoder uses local color tables for each frame instead of a global color table.

Does anybody know if there is a possibility to set a global color table for all frames in the GifBitmapEncoder or is there a free library for .NET which can do that?

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought of creating a sprited PNG instead?  For this, you put all of the images next to each other on one big PNG, and then when you use them, you extract a rectangle where the image is.

One of my colleagues used our free DotImage Photo SDK to make a simple app to do it.   You could use the source and product for free.  He also shows how to extract rectangles in CSS:

http://www.atalasoft.com/cs/blogs/jake/archive/2008/12/22/spritify-writing-a-css-image-sprite-generator-with-dotimage.aspx